# create custom shape with android studio?

Tags: android

I want to create this shape for my app but I can't create this shape in the editor

[image]

Comment: You should be able to make a nine patch for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a drawable called `bg_custom_textview.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/SomeColor"
        />
<corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Use this as your textview background,

```
<TextView
android:background="@drawable/bg_custom_textview"
/>
```